# What does this "label" mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I was reading some c++ code, and i saw something interesting.

The code was something like this:

```
repeat:
    ...code here....
fallback:
    ...code here....
start:
        ....another code....
```

This is the first time i am seeing this kind of "labels" in c++ code, i called the labels cos i have seen something similar in assembly code where the code is divided into sections with different titles which end with colon.

I am asking you what does that mean, and of what use it can be ?

Comment: Look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful

Comment: Well, you said it yourself. It's a label. What do you want from me?!

Comment: See also [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) for a discussion from the early days of SO.  There is useful information in amongst the answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a label, to which you can jump using a `goto`.

Whether one should use `goto`s in a program is another matter entirely.

Comment: Hmm..how come i haven't seen goto in any c++ code i've seen ?

Comment: @dada did you see any `switch`? :-)

Comment: Because `goto`s tend to be discouraged in C and C++.

Comment: @dada:  You can find the answer to that by searching for "goto" and "harmful" together on either StackOverflow or Google.  I guarantee there will be many pages debating the utility of `goto`.

Comment: @Pavel: No, no switch anywhere.

Comment: @dada - because the number of times that a `goto` is the right flow control construct is very, very small.  It's almost always the sign of some serious spaghetti code.

Comment: Because many people frown on them; they can produce **very** obscure code. (OTOH, not all the things that people propose to replace the use of `goto` are necessarily clearer either. Some code is just nasty.)

Comment: @dada : Rather more important is whether or not you see goto in your code. If you see, be happy for all the reasons quoted by others

Comment: Wow. I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw), then at [22:10](https://youtu.be/ZTqHjjm86Bw?t=1330) I asked myself _"what is `bla:` in C++?"_, searched on StackOverflow, and found this answer... And guess who's the author of the video? What a coincidence!

Answer (score 2):

A label is generally the target of a [`goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eeb0e5w.aspx) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are used as targets for [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34dt9cd%28VS.80%29.aspx), but, if you put a label, you are not forced to use goto, if you do not see any goto in the code you are reading, the people/guy who wrote that code probably used them for actually labeling purposes (duh!).

Comment: I have no idea, is the only thing I can imagine if they are using labels but not using goto. Maybe their editor lets them fold the code at labels, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are used with `goto` and `switch/case` statements, when they are used to direct the flow of control.   However, labels may also be used absent any `goto` statements (case labels must only appear in a `switch` statement) as means of identifying particular code segments -- i.e., somewhat like a comment, though in reality more like a title.  If you're not seeing any `switch` or `goto` statements, I suspect the code author is simply using them to organize his code.